# h2o automl leaderboard frame not working in R

Tags: h2o, automl

I am currently using h2o automl feature in R environment and I see the leaderboard showing up none in the logs even though I have provided the dataset to it. Appreciate if someone can answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to this [known bug](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5402) which is causing NaNs in the leaderboard in non-US locales.  It has been fixed on the [nightly releases](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html), so feel free to download one of those, or you can wait until the next stable release of H2O (3.18.0.5 will be released next week).

If this is not the same bug, please provide more info, including a reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you Erin for your comment. But did not understand the point about non-US locales.

Comment: If you're seeing NaNs on the leaderboard, this is caused by a bug triggered by system locale settings. See `Sys.setlocale()`.